# ExtJS: How to detect when buttons being added to the panel will go to the next line?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4, panel

I have a situation where I dynamically add buttons to a panel, horizontally. Size of the buttons vary(based on the text of the button). When no more buttons fit a row, ExtJS automatically starts adding to the next row. Is there any way to detect when ExtJS is about to add to the next row ?  I attempted to get the width of the button as it is being added and have a running sum of the widths so I would know whether the next button will exceed the width of the panel but the width is not defined as I am adding a button to the panel as shown below.

```
var btn = Ext.widget( 'button', {
    text : 'variable length text'
});
btn.getWidth(); //undefined
panel.add(btn);
```

I guess I am looking for an event when ExtJs adds to the next row but any other approach would be nice also. Thanks !

Comment: extjs adds a new row because you're using the default layout, and the width is undefined because before add the button isn't rendered

Comment: So the problem is, what you need to do when a button add a new row?

Comment: @Mr.Bruno Rather than adding to a new row, I want to change the text of the existing buttons to the new text.

Comment: So you need to change button text if they are in a different row? Please add a [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/) to show us what are you talking about

Comment: No, I would change the text of the existing buttons on row1, rather than adding a new button to row2.

Comment: I think the only way is get the y position of the button after adding it